# CORS --- Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: express, heroku, redux, cors, fetch

I'm having difficulty with getting CORS to work. I'm trying to fetch data from a Heroku app I set up. I'm fetching from Redux, and using ExpressJS for the backend. I've been looking through the CORS docs but still can't figure it out. [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

This is how it looks in Express

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors')

router.options('/', cors())

router.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ['*']);
   res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
   res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
   next();
});

router.get('/', cors(), function(req, res, next) {
   res.json({...})
}
```

I have the proxy set up in my app to http://localhost:3001/, but my app is running on 3000. I'm including this in case it could be the issue, but I don't know that it is.

My Redux file is set up like this

```
return dispatch => {
  const url = "https://app-name.herokuapp.com/users";
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text' }
})
```

The full error is: "Failed to load https://app-name.herokuapp.com/users: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access."

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    next();
});
```

Comment: Now I get this error "Failed to load http://app-name.com/users: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)"